# Blink and rotation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to achieve an infinite blink and rotation together, but the problem I face is quite weird, the blinking which should occur at a regular interval of 500ms, happens nicely for a while then disappears and appears back again.

Also I went through lot of questions around blinking but my test case is different. I can't keep the 0% 50% 100% in the keyframes to get the blinking working because I'd want the span to blink at a particular percentage I specify.

For example: I'd want the span to blink at 100deg or 90deg, so I should be able to specify the blink timing by specifying the exact percentage value.

Here's my work so far, any help would be appreciated. http://jsfiddle.net/8UQ8X/7/ (includes vendor prefixes)

```
<div>
  <span></span>
 </div>

<style>
div{
    position: fixed;
    width:3px;
    height:100px;
    left: 300px;
    top: 100px;
    border: 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1) solid;
    -webkit-animation: spin 500ms steps(30) infinite; 
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center; 
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

span{
    display:block;
    width: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-animation: blink 500ms infinite steps(1); 
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)
    }
    to{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)
    } 
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    // I should be able to any percentage value to get the span blink at a particular degree.
   // for now I am trying to blink the span at 0%, the beginning, later I might change it to 50% or something
    0% {background: #fff}
    1% {background: none;}
} 

body{
    background: #232323;
}
</style>
```

Comment: might it be the browser skipping that frame?

Comment: I took that into consideration, thats why if you look at the animation timing for the DIV, I have used 30steps in 500ms which is 60fps. I ran alongside chrome flags for the FPS meter, the code is bare minimal and it runs at 60fps all the time too, so the 500ms and steps 30 is doing the job right. Also if the frame skipping was the scenario then, if you have looked at the fiddle, the blink works fine for 10 or 11 times then disappears for the same duration and back to 10-11 times blinking.

Comment: If you change blink to 0% and 20% you can see that blink works always, but sometimes misses the mark, starting after the 12 o'clock position.

Comment: ...don't forget your moz prefix. I couldn't see it at all in FF until i added it

Comment: Exactly. I am trying to figure out why that occurs. Because if you disable the spin and just make the blink happen, still that glitch shows.

Comment: @Phlume Sorry I missed that out. :(

Comment: you want it to blink at 90deg ***and*** 100deg or just one of those points?

Comment: @KingKing at any point is what I am trying to achieve but if the blink satisfies the condition at one degree then i should work at any deg.

Comment: @MeherRanjan when flashing, I think it need a period of time to light up (not just at an exact point of time which means the time of flashing is just nearly ZERO). So I think you don't need to use `steps()` timing function here, for example if you want it to flash at `90deg`, the timing range is about from 24% to 26% (the exact value is `25%`), Also you should use `background:transparent` rather than `background:none`, as I tested `background:none` works unstably (sometimes does not work), here's the demo http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/8UQ8X/9/

Comment: @KingKing nice. that works well but not long enough, if you see your example, much better performing, after like a count of 50 blinks, it disappears for a short while and starts appearing again. any idea why?

Comment: it looks fine to me, however it's just for 90deg, looks like it's not good, not sure what causing the issue, however using `steps()` timing function will divide 360deg into 30 steps of 12deg, that means there is no continuity here. Even if using `linear` timing function, it does also not rotate continuously (like as real rotating we see). It's because of how rotating is done in animation, the step is not small enough (while the smaller it is, the better visual experience is). The effect you're trying to achieve is not what animation can help best.

Comment: @KingKing If we remove the spin completely and just observe the blinking, we can see there's some missing block which doesn't let it blink consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : [Animation](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_eirenaios/8UQ8X/11/)

```
  .i{
    position: fixed;
    width:10px;
    height:150px;
    left: 300px;
    top: 100px;
    border: 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1) solid;
    -webkit-animation: spin 500ms steps(30) infinite; 
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center; 
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-animation: spin 500ms steps(30) infinite; 
    -moz-transform-origin: center center; 
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
}

span{
    display:block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px; 
    border: 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1) solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-animation: blink 500ms infinite steps(1); 
    -moz-animation: blink 500ms infinite steps(1); 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:liner;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)
    }
    to{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)
    } 
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from{
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg)
    }
    to{
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg)
    } 
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink { 
    0% {background: #fff}
    1% {background: none;} 
} 


@-moz-keyframes blink { 
    0% {background: #fff}
    1% {background: none;} 
} 


body{
    background: #232323;
}
```

Comment: I don't how changing the easing effect would solve the issue. Moreover the problem still persists.